# Read From CSV File with System.IO and Handles

Tags: haskell

I was trying to get familiar with System.IO and handles. I want to just read a csv file, put a line of comma separated integers into a list, put that list into a list of lists, then put the next line into the list of lists, and so forth until the end of the file. I can read the file, and read a line of the file, but am struggling to make something that will do what I'm trying to do. The csv file, "1.csv" looks like this:

```
1,2,3,4
4,3,2,1
12,13
```

The code I have so far is as follows. It finds an error at the line "_ -> x:xs". I'm not used to using case x of at all so I might not be using that right, but it seems like a way to go with this. I know a lot of what I'm doing is wrong, but I'm not really sure how to go further.

```
import System.IO
xs = []
xss = []

readTheLine = do handle <- openFile "1.csv" ReadMode
                 x <- hGetChar handle
                 case x of
                    '\n' -> xs:xss
                     _ -> x:xs
                     '' -> putStrLn xss

main = readTheLine
```

I'm also pretty sure '' wouldn't signal the end of the file, but not sure what to do here and was trying to show what I'm going for.

Comment: You appear to be lacking basic knowledge of Haskell, like its immutability. Don't mess with System.IO or handles until you know how to write a pure function that takes a String containing the content of a CSV and returns a list of list of integers.

Comment: As in actually take the integers from the CSV? That's exactly what I'm trying to do, but I thought this was a way to do it. In searching how to do it I mostly just found different libraries like Text.CSV, but thought System.IO is more common. I've been studying Haskell for a bit and know about pure functions, and have worked with some I/O, but not with files.

Comment: From the content of the CSV I mean. Hardcode the string `"1,2,3,4\n4,3,2,1\n12,13"` in your program, and write a pure function that can successfully parse it. Only once you have that working should you mess with `hGetChar` and such.